# Scipy remove unwanted frequency from plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have computed a scipy.signal.spectrogram. Now i want to filter and not show some unwanted frequencies on the y axis.

I want to remove the freqs between 47 - 53 and 97 - 103 completely. This cannot be done only by manipulating the plot since the freqs still distorts the color intensity of the plot.

I have tried different things with zero result.

```
Fs = 500       # Define the sampling frequency,
interval = int(Fs/6)   # ... the interval size,
overlap = int(interval * 0.99)  # ... and the overlap intervals
import matplotlib
import pylab
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from scipy.stats import lognorm
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)

f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(np.array(sze), fs=Fs, nperseg=interval, noverlap=overlap, mode='psd', scaling='density', nfft=1000, window='hann')
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
Sxx = 10*np.log10(Sxx)

# Sxx = np.concatenate((Sxx[(t < 47)], Sxx[(t > 53)]), axis=0) 
# f = np.concatenate((f[(f < 47)], f[(f > 53)]), axis=0)
#normalize_color= colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.amin(Sxx), vmax=np.amax(Sxx))
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, cmap='jet')# Plot the result
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("Spectrogram: Sample Rate 500 Hz ")
plt.ylabel("Freq")
plt.xlabel("Time (sec)")
```

The code i have commented out did not work.

Here's my plot:

[image: spectrogram]

The output of the signal.spectrogram is two np.arrays: Sxx.shape = (501, 1918) and f is (501,). I expect that red line at 50 Hz is removed and the label on y isn't showing. also that the other frequency color changes.

signal data: https://tmpfiles.org/172982/foo.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are three options: chopping the problem lines out, like you tried; setting the problem lines to `np.nan`; or limiting the color axis.

In the commented out line: `# Sxx = np.concatenate((Sxx[(t < 47)], Sxx[(t > 53)]), axis=0)` you used `t`, not `f`.

Here's a self-contained example showing the original and the three options I proposed; in this case I assume we want to see the third harmonic at 150Hz more clearly.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fs = 500       # Define the sampling frequency,
Tf = 4

t = np.arange(0, Tf * Fs) / Fs
sze = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * 50 * t)
       + 0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 100 * t)
       + 0.01 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 150 * t))

interval = int(Fs/6)   # ... the interval size,
overlap = int(interval * 0.99)  # ... and the overlap intervals
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)

f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(np.array(sze), fs=Fs,
                               nperseg=interval, noverlap=overlap,
                               mode='psd', scaling='density',
                               nfft=1000, window='hann')

Sxx = 10*np.log10(Sxx)

plt.close('all')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

pcm = ax[0,0].pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, cmap='jet', shading='auto')
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax[0,0])
ax[0,0].set_ylabel("Freq")
ax[0,0].set_title('original')

# option 1: remove some entries
mask = (f < 40) | (f > 60)
Sxx2 = Sxx[mask,:]
f2 = f[mask]

pcm = ax[0,1].pcolormesh(t, f2, Sxx2, cmap='jet', shading='auto')
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax[0,1])
ax[0,1].set_title('cut out frequency range')

# option 2: set some entries to NaN
mask3 = (f < 40) | (f > 60)
Sxx3 = Sxx.copy()
Sxx3[~mask3,:] = np.nan

ax[1,0].pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx3, cmap='jet', shading='auto')
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax[1,0])
ax[1,0].set_ylabel("Freq")
ax[1,0].set_xlabel("Time (sec)")
ax[1,0].set_title('replace with nan')

# # option 3: limit color axis
pcm = ax[1,1].pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, cmap='jet', shading='auto')
pcm.set_clim(vmax=-60)
cbar = fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax[1,1])
ax[1,1].set_xlabel("Time (sec)")
ax[1,1].set_title('adjust clim')
```

[image]